# Все запросы на один Servlet - JavaEE

Tags: java, ajax, java-ee, servlet

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как сделать так что бы все запросы от клиента к серверу приходили на основную `Serlvet-у`? Тобишь что бы не указывать в каждом случае на какую сервлету нужно делать запрос, а на одну. К примеру есть сервлета `ServerController` и ещё 5 сервлет которые выполняют каждая свою функцию. 
Использую `ajax`. И все запросы будут выглядеть, к примеру, так: `/ServletController/edit/1`.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял вопрос так, что нужно направить все запросы к одному сервлету-контроллеру.
Тогда надо в web.xml для servlet-mapping задать `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
вот так:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServerController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

тогда все остальные `<servlet-mapping>`, которые позволяют обращаться к сервлетам в обход ServerController необходимо удалить.
Это похоже на шаблон проектирования FrontController.

Comment: Если я удалю у остальных сервлетов их urlPattern-ы то я их не смогу вызвать.

Comment: И ещё. При `/*` абсолютно все запросы будут идти через этот сервет. Даже запросы на файлы и прочее.

Comment: ну так через ServerController и будете дальше пробрасывать если надо)

Comment: а как быть с файлами?

Comment: приведите пример: какой запрос, какой файл?

Comment: файл js или картинка.